# How can IOTA detect local tangle corruption?

Tags: tangle, iota-network

When our local tangle changes, how can IOTA detect that? I researched online but can't found a clear answer. Can anyone explain the detailed mechanism for local data corruption detection and recovery? Or provide some materials related.

Thanks!!